# Deprecated segues in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, xcode6.4

So I followed the tutorial on making a segue here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

When I Ctrl-drag from a button to a view controller I get the options Push, Modal, Popover, Replace and Custom. The tutorial states clearly that all of those are deprecated (except custom, which I guess is for more complicated segues). The deployment target of my project is 8.3 and I use xcode 6.4.

Could someone please shine some brightness unto this confusing mess?

Comment: Instead of Modal you should use Present Modally. What is the confusion. Apple Docs are so much explanatory.

Comment: @user1354603 did my answer help you understand the confusion?

Comment: @AppDevGuy Well it's still confusing, not the part about some segues being deprecated and what has replaced them, the confusing part is that when I tried to make a segue I could only choose deprecated segues. When I added a navigation controller I was able to choose the newer non-deprecated segues so I guess the problem is solved, I just don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: Could you screen shot what you're doing to bring it up? I can't seem to replicate the issue.

Comment: Yes show an screen I'm facing the same thing, can't get show segues only push. What I saw is that enabling size classes it allows you to see the new segues. I'm stumped as to why.

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso the reason why you can use the new ones with size class enabled is due to auto configuration of sizes; the most recent devices are running iOS8 and therefore use the most recent segues. Therefore the conversion of segues is included in the conversion of size classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you read the documents from Apple about the differences; this document more explicitly explains the differences: [Apple Segue Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/BackwardCompatibilityofActiveSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH46-SW1)

> In apps that target versions below iOS 8.0, adaptive segues are converted to legacy segues. In apps targeting iOS version 8.0 or greater, legacy segues are upgraded to adaptive segues when size classes are enabled for the project.

These legacy Segues are your *Push, Modal, Popover and Replace*.

When Xcode 6 was released, the newer functions *Show, Show Detail, Present Modally, and Present as Popover* were released.

These new functions are designed to replace the old, and are targeted for iOS Versions 8 onwards, but are capable of function in earlier versions, as they are adaptive.

The details of the segues are stated exactly as they are in the [Apple Segue Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) that you attached. The document tells you that the newer segues are adaptive. *Show* has a few more features, presumable for a more flawless operation, quite possibly in regards to conserving memory/preventing memory usage spikes at run time.

[image: Segue Image from Apple]

In the Apple Segue Doc (the first link), the comparisons are broken down as shown below (there is another image on the site):

[image: Updated Segues]

If you plan on releasing applications to devices with versions below iOS 8.0, you could consider using the *legacy* segues, however, if you are only planning on releasing to devices compatible with 8.0 onwards, Show, Show Detail, etc.